# Angular2 http default headers common Authorization tokens

Tags: http, header, angular, authorization, token

In angular 1, I was able to manipulate the http object so the request header for a post included authentication like this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Token " + sessionobject.token;

return $http({

    method: 'POST',
    url: SERVER_ENVIRONMENT + 'updatepath',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Data-Type': 'json'
    },
    data: { 
        id : id,
        ...
    }
})
```

Can you please help me find the equvilant in Angular 2 that generates the same post request? many thnx in advance

Comment: already replied: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chandermani said in his question you can specify your own options for requests. You can define things statically or a bit more dynamically by overriden the merge method. With the latter you can extend request options based of provided options for the current request.

For more details have a look at this question:

- [Handling refresh tokens using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907151/handling-refresh-tokens-using-rxjs)

Since you use tokens, an important feature is that they expire after an amount of time. This means that you need to refresh them based on refresh tokens. This can be done transparently in Angular2 by extending the Http class and leveraging observable operators like flatMap.

For more details have a look at this question:

- [Handling refresh tokens using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907151/handling-refresh-tokens-using-rxjs)

Answer (score 5):

You extend the Angular2 class `BaseRequestOptions` to provide custom headers for all Http calls

```
class MyOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
 header:Headers=new Header({
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
 });
}
```

This class override can then be plugged into DI so that for the request options http picks `MyOptions`

```
bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: MyOptions})]);
```

The issue with this approach is that the token should be available during bootstrapping, which is not the case most of the time.

The other option is to create a custom `http` service. One such implementations is available here https://gist.github.com/chandermani/9166abe6e6608a31f471